# What is the regex for php to get the href value in all stylesheet tags from HTML?

Tags: php, css, regex, preg-match-all

What is a general way to grab all href tags using regex and preg_match_all to get the href value given the  tag is not always in order.

Example:

```
<link href="foo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link type="text/css" href="bar.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bar1.css"/>
<link type="text/css" href="bar2.css" rel="stylesheet"></link>
<link href="path/foo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

Should result in :

```
Array(
'foo.css',
'bar.css',
'bar1.css',
'bar2.css',
'path/foo.css',
)
```

Comment: The general way is NOT to do it, but use `SimpleDOM` or sth similar instead.

Comment: I am reading from files that contain only these elements.  Thanks tho. -- Also, SimpleDOM / etc --- very slow and are for DOM processing of complete HTML pages, not for file parsing.

Comment: As for actual reasons to downvote: [Regex is not suitable for parsing HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1331430), and you didn't show much effort in solving the issue.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - with or without the heading, downvotes happen on the best of questions BECAUSE it is anonymous.  Thank you for your justification for downvoting. While regex is not suitable for parsing HTML -- it is suitable for parsing HTML segments (for example where the above is the ONLY contents of the file, a DOM parse would not work as there is no DOM).  Further, use of a DOM parser assumes that one is installed and enabled.  DOM parsing is also slow, and works only with "rendered" content.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - By rendered content, what I mean is that the page is rendered into the DOM, and the resulting page may differ from the source itself.  When working with online pages, of course DOM is a better solution --  most of the time.

Comment: Okay, your use case is justifiable. PHP also has DOM parsers, but of course it involves loading the HTML into a virtual DOM which is slower. What I don't understand is your other "best questions" being downvoted, I can only see one other question in your profile and it is a bit too broad for the scope of this Q&A (imho).

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - also... wow... did you check out the wacky formatting of that response -- which somehow got 4430 upvotes....  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454   --- brutal. especially the bottom half.  The author took no care in posting that response !!

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - I have read the docs on this subject, and what I have witnessed is closed "software tools commonly used by programmers" questions under "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." as the reason.  So unless it is saying, "I am using XYZ IDE, and need to know how to ..." ...  the questions are closed. Which is odd as those IDE's have help built in typically to answer the how to

Comment: Making a question about a specific IDE/tool is okay, but asking for a recommendation (e.g. "what's the best IDE for...") gets closed.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - But not to actually FIND the IDE in the first place that will resolve the problem, and given the response.  It's like blocking reference on a Doctor -- you want a good one, so you would like to know peoples experiences, good and bad, and come with what/who is best currently -- not just popular.  Sometimes, there are obscure ones which are VERY helpful.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that there are new IDEs surfacing all the time and answers are often based on personal preference. Stack Overflow prefers reasonably-scoped questions which can be objectively answered, while recommendation questions usually go into an endless discussion.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Perhaps even a "list the current best IDE's that you know of" --- for example, if i wanted to find an IDE that did drag & drop dev which supported PHP as the backend, and HTML5 for the frontend -- one correct answer would be Delphi XE5 .  But unless that is documented somewhere, ----  makes it difficult to locate it, and delphi really wasn't an HTML IDE, it has been known as Object Pascal.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - I understand. But an endless discussion showing a consolidated list WITH REASONS would also be helpful... much more so than random google searches until something pops up that "looks" good (but usually turns out to be garbage)

Comment: Yes, that kind of question is helpful nonetheless (you can find many of these questions closed, but still available here due to their usefulness), but unfortunately recommendation questions are outside of the Q&A scope, so it may be better to ask for a list of software in some other forum.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - Thats essentially what I have been doing. With regards to my other question being "general", it is actually rather specific to something that is not really being addressed. I do have a solution for that as well -- specifically that question. A hint (it involves the jQuery DnD component + JSON response from server for element list, and UL/LI + a <div> for drop, and textarea)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex expression your looking for is something like this, but will require a bit further refinement:

```
<link\s+(?:[^>]*?\s+)?href="([^"]*)"
```

Testing against

```
<link href="foo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

The returned value is

```
<link href="foo.css"
```

Here's a good place to test out your expressions:  http://regexpal.com/

Comment: excellent response.  you are missing the parameters that direct recursive searches across multiple strings, but you do have the exception for the closing tag to terminate the search on that line.

Comment: `<link[^>]* href="([^"]*)"` is what I use, however it assumes that the href is enclosed in quotes.

Answer (score 2):

**Parsing** is the way to go:

```
$x = file_get_contents("foo.txt");
$xml = simplexml_load_string("<links>$x</links>");
$results = array();

foreach ($xml->link as $link)
    $results[] = (string)$link['href'];
```

see it working: https://eval.in/132898

Comment: Interesting solution. +1 for creativity :). Does this work with inline comment blocks such as  <!-- FOO --> and <![CDATA]>  ?

Comment: @SanuelJackson don't know, try and let me know :-)

Comment: Yes it does.  Now going to see if it skips other stuff.  [https://eval.in/132982](https://eval.in/132982)

Comment: It breaks when there is other stuff mixed in the content. I havn't tried with plain text or /* */ type block comments. [https://eval.in/132985](https://eval.in/132985) .  Still a very cool method -- sort of a cheat, if you know that there is nothing else in the file at all.

Answer (score 0):

i would say:

```
preg_match_all('/href=\"([a-z1-9\/.]+)\"/img', $head, $matches)
```

Comment: close, but your regex limits the chars that can be inside the href to a-z, 1-9, and / .

Comment: not exactly, /i provides you case insesitiveness, may by with _ char, it should catch most of all ascii possibilities.

Comment: I did notice the inline search parameters, and you are correct, i should have stated  'A-Z, a-z, 1-9, / and .'  :)